# getting Netgear WNDA3100 USB adapter working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, 15.10, ndiswrapper

I have been struggling with this problem for about 2 days now...
Here is where I am:

When I run `ndiswrapper -l`:

```
bcmn43xx64 : driver installed
    device (0846:9011) present
```

When I run `ndiswrapper -v`:

```
utils version: '1.9', utils version needed by module: '1.9'
module details:
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/updates/dkms/ndiswrapper.ko
version:        1.59
vermagic:       4.2.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

However, when I run `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` nothing happens.
Note: Here are the ndis module reported as installed under Synaptic PM:

```
ndiswrapper 1.59-6
ndisgtk 0.8.5-1ubuntu1
ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 1.59-6
ndiswrapper-source 1.59-6
ndiswrapper-dkms 1.59-6
```

For some reason, the `ndiswrapper-common` module can't be loaded without removing `ndiswrapper`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know I could order the Netgear WNA1100 that is reported to work out the box, but that'd be too easy, and I am trying desperately to learn linux.

thanks,
robbo

Comment: the formatting looks terrible with my question--- sorry about that!

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: We'd also like to see: `dmesg | grep ndis`

Comment: Okay, I finally got it working by reading and rereading and reapply steps at this forum posting, thanks in large part to you, chili555  http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1964173.html

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get wireless working by reading and rereading posts at this site: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1964173.html as chili555 worked with another user. I think by removing and reinserting the USB transceiver allowed it to make the connection. On reboot, I did have to reinsert the USB device once again to get a connection.
Thanks for all that responded.
Robbo

note: Since that first reboot, the wlan connects automatically on each subsequent reboot.